# Implementing a custom IAuthorizationPolicyProvider with database access

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core 2.1, I have an implementation of a `IAuthorizationPolicyProvider` using ctor injection for a database context. As providers must be registered as singletons, this throws as database contexts are scoped.

So instead, I inject the connection string settings object in the ctor, then use an options builder and create a context inside the call to `GetPolicyAsync`:

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(this.connectionStrings.MyContextConnection);

using (var context = new MyContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
{
    // ...
}
```

The use case is called out at the start of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.1), is there a safe and more efficient way to get a context within the method call?

Comment: I think because AuthorizationPolicyProvider is scoped to requests. You cannot use scoped things in Singletons.

Comment: Actually, it needs to be a singleton, I'll add some info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resolving **scoped service** from **singleton service**, you could try register `IServiceProvider` in the singleton service.

```
public class DbPolicyProvider : IAuthorizationPolicyProvider
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public DbPolicyProvider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    public async Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetDefaultPolicyAsync()
    {
        return await GetPolicyAsync("DbPolicy");
    }

    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
    {
        using (var db = _serviceProvider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>())
        {
            var policys = db.Policys.Where(p => p.Name == policyName).ToList();
            var build = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();
            foreach (var policy in policys)
            {
                build.RequireClaim(policyName, policy.Config);
            }
            return Task.FromResult(build.Build());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Tao Zhou's answer didn't work for me due to [`IServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider?view=netcore-2.2) not having the method `CreateScope()`.

Instead I used the static method `CreateScope()` from the [`ServiceProviderServiceExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions?view=aspnetcore-2.2) class.

```
using (var db = ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.CreateScope(_serviceProvider).ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>())
```